# Unable to embed javascript in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm a little rusty here and note sure what is going on. Here is my file:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import {CONTENT_LINKS_PRESENTABLE, CONTENT_LINKS_SLUG} from '../../globals'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

function Navbar() {
  let jsx = (<div className="navbar">
      <div className="navbar-item">
        <Link to="/" id="navbar-brand">Daniel Pahor</Link>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar-items">
      
        {for (let content in CONTENT_LINKS_PRESENTABLE) {
          <div className="navbar-item">
            <Link to={CONTENT_LINKS_SLUG[content]} className="navbar-link">{CONTENT_LINKS_PRESENTABLE[content]}</Link>
          </div>
        }}
      
      </div>
    </div>)
    
  return jsx;
}

export default Navbar;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Parsing error: unexpected token
```

On line 13 (i.e. when the for loop begins)

Considering that I have embedded the JS code in the {} tags I'm not sure why this is failing

Comment: why not just map over the array? `{CONTENT_LINKS_PRESENTABLE.map( (link) => <div>...</div>)` alternatively you can do this for loop before you define `jsx` and push items into an array that you then use to render the navbar items

Comment: Or if `CONTENT_LINKS_PRESENTABLE` is an object, you can do `Object.keys(CONTENT_LINKS_PRESENTABLE).map( link => <div>...</div> )` to transform the object keys into a mappable array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Comment: @SethLutske i doubt its an object since the way `content` is used is as a lookup key `<Link to={CONTENT_LINKS_SLUG[content]} className="navbar-link">{CONTENT_LINKS_PRESENTABLE[content]}</Link>`. I believe its an array of strings :)

Comment: If it's an object, there's also a good question already: [How to loop an object in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39965579/1218980)

Comment: @JohnRuddell I thought maybe it was an object because why else would you use a `for var in` loop...But like you said...who knows

Comment: Ah okay, the map() idea is pretty lit, I like it a lot, I'll try that

Answer (score 2):

Replace for with CONTENT_LINKS_PRESENTABLE.map(/* ... */) so it will return array of nodes. Don't forget for keys though!

```js
{
CONTENT_LINKS_PRESENTABLE.map(content => (
          <div className="navbar-item" key={content}>
            <Link to={CONTENT_LINKS_SLUG[content]} className="navbar-link">
              {CONTENT_LINKS_PRESENTABLE[content]}
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only able to pass in expressions. `if` and `for` are not expressions and so cannot be used. See the react docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions-as-props). How you can get around this.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import {CONTENT_LINKS_PRESENTABLE, CONTENT_LINKS_SLUG} from '../../globals'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <div className="navbar-item">
        <Link to="/" id="navbar-brand">Daniel Pahor</Link>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar-items">
        {CONTENT_LINK_PRESENTABLE.map(content => (
           <div className="navbar-item" key={content}>
            <Link to={CONTENT_LINKS_SLUG[content]} className="navbar-link">{CONTENT_LINKS_PRESENTABLE[content]}</Link>
          </div> 
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Don't forget you need to pass in a key whenever you generate list items as this is what helps react identify whether or not items have changed as specified by the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the syntax error is that a `for` loop is not a JavaScript expression, per official React docs ["JSX in Depth"](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) section ["JavaScript Expressions as Children"](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions-as-children):

> You can pass any JavaScript expression as children, by enclosing it within `{}`.

Also from the section ["JavaScript Expressions as Props"](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions-as-props):

> `if` statements and `for` loops are not expressions in JavaScript, so they can’t be used in JSX directly. Instead, you can put these in the surrounding code.

As suggested by the other answers, a good alternative is to use `map`.