# React Native - Can I pass state objects to child component from parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

New to React Native.
I am creating a registration form where I have created a form wizard, each step of the has a different component. I want to handle every input's state from Parent Component.

Error:

```
 Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found:
 object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a
 collection of children, use an array instead.
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:977)
     in ScrollView (at KeyboardAwareHOC.js:397)
     in _class (at Content.js:125)
     in Content (at connectStyle.js:384)
     in Styled(Content) (at RegisterBusiness.js:271)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in Container (at connectStyle.js:384)
     in Styled(Container) (at RegisterBusiness.js:242)
     in RegisterBusiness (at SceneView.js:9)
     in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.js:478)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:58)
     in Screen (at StackViewCard.js:42)
     in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.js:26)
     in Container (at StackViewLayout.js:507)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.js:401)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
     in withOrientation (at StackView.js:49)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in Transitioner (at StackView.js:19)
     in StackView (at createNavigator.js:57)
     in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:11)
     in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
     in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:9)
     in SceneView (at DrawerView.js:87)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in AndroidDrawerLayout (at DrawerLayoutAndroid.android.js:205)
     in DrawerLayoutAndroid (at DrawerView.js:84)
     in DrawerView (at createNavigator.js:57)
     in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
     in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:9)
     in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
     in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:57)
     in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
     in NavigationContainer (at App.js:135)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in Root (at connectStyle.js:384)
     in Styled(Root) (at App.js:134)
     in App (at renderApplication.js:34)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)

 This error is located at:
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:977)
     in ScrollView (at KeyboardAwareHOC.js:397)
     in _class (at Content.js:125)
     in Content (at connectStyle.js:384)
     in Styled(Content) (at RegisterBusiness.js:271)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in Container (at connectStyle.js:384)
     in Styled(Container) (at RegisterBusiness.js:242)
     in RegisterBusiness (at SceneView.js:9)
     in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.js:478)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:58)
     in Screen (at StackViewCard.js:42)
     in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.js:26)
     in Container (at StackViewLayout.js:507)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.js:401)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
     in withOrientation (at StackView.js:49)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in Transitioner (at StackView.js:19)
     in StackView (at createNavigator.js:57)
     in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:11)
     in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
     in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:9)
     in SceneView (at DrawerView.js:87)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in AndroidDrawerLayout (at DrawerLayoutAndroid.android.js:205)
     in DrawerLayoutAndroid (at DrawerView.js:84)
     in DrawerView (at createNavigator.js:57)
     in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
     in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:9)
     in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
     in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:57)
     in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
     in NavigationContainer (at App.js:135)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in Root (at connectStyle.js:384)
     in Styled(Root) (at App.js:134)
     in App (at renderApplication.js:34)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)

 This error is located at:
     in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:9)
     in SceneView (at DrawerView.js:87)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in AndroidDrawerLayout (at DrawerLayoutAndroid.android.js:205)
     in DrawerLayoutAndroid (at DrawerView.js:84)
     in DrawerView (at createNavigator.js:57)
     in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
     in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:9)
     in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
     in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:57)
     in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
     in NavigationContainer (at App.js:135)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in Root (at connectStyle.js:384)
     in Styled(Root) (at App.js:134)
     in App (at renderApplication.js:34)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)

 This error is located at:
     in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:9)
     in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
     in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:57)
     in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
     in NavigationContainer (at App.js:135)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in Root (at connectStyle.js:384)
     in Styled(Root) (at App.js:134)
     in App (at renderApplication.js:34)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)

 This error is located at:
     in NavigationContainer (at App.js:135)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in Root (at connectStyle.js:384)
     in Styled(Root) (at App.js:134)
     in App (at renderApplication.js:34)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
     in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33) throwOnInvalidObjectType
```

Parent Component: Register.js

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        pageCount: 1,
        pageName : 'merchantReg',
        stepName: "Basic Details",
        merchantReg: {
          contactperson: "STAR",
          contactno: "1234567890",
          altcontactno: "",
          email: "",
          altemail: "",
          legalname: "",
          dbaname: "",
          typeofpos: "NA",
          noofpos: "0",
          pacakage: "NA",
          natureofbusiness: "NA",
        },
        businessReg : {
          businessType: "",
          gststatus:"",
          gstno:"",
          panno:"",
          tinno:"",
          shopno:"",
          salestaxno:"",
          officepremisis:"",
          currentlocation:"",
          businesslastyear:"",
          averagebillamt:"",
          expectedcardbusiness:"",
        },
        residenceaddress:"",
        bankDetails : {
          bankname:"",
          bankbranch:"",
          accountname:"",
          accountno:"",
          ifsccode:"",
          aadharno:"",
          posstatement:"",
          posfirc:"NA",
          fircfreq:"NA",
        },
        mdr:{
          debitcardpremium:"",
          debitcardclassic:"",
          creditcardclassic:"",
          creditcardpremium:"",
          foreigncard:"",
          terminal_service_fee:"",
          terminal_type:"",
          posamount:""
        }
    }
 }


_storetoState = (key1,value) => {
  var page = this.state.pageName;
  this.setState({
    [page]: {
          ...this.state[page],
          [key1] : value
    }
  })
}

StepsofRegistrations = async () => {
  switch(this.state.pageCount){
    case 1: {

        requiredFields = [];
        requiredFields.push('contactperson','contactno','email','legalname','dbaname','typeofpos');
        return (<MerchantRegister value={this.state.merchantReg} handleChange={this._storetoState} />);
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        requiredFields = [];
        requiredFields.push('contactperson','contactno','email','legalname','dbaname','typeofpos');
        return(<ShopDetails  value={this.state.businessReg} handleChange={this._storetoState}/>);
        break;
    }

  }
}


  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header noShadow>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
              <Icon name='arrow-back'/>
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title style={{
              width: 215
            }}>
              Register a New Business
            </Title>
          </Body>
          <Right></Right>
        </Header>

          <View style={{
              paddingHorizontal:30,
              padding:10,
              backgroundColor:'#eee',
              flexDirection:'row',
              justifyContent:'space-between',
              elevation:1
            }}>
              <View><Text style={{fontSize:18}}>{this.state.stepName}</Text></View>
              <View><Text style={{fontSize:17,textAlign:'right'}}>{this.state.pageCount}/6</Text></View>
            </View>

        <Content>

          <View style={{
            borderWidth:0.2,
            borderColor:'#ccc',
          }}></View>

            {this.StepsofRegistrations()}


        </Content>

      </Container>
    );
  }
```

One fo my Child component all my other components are same as the below code they have only changed names.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, AsyncStorage, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Picker, Label, Item, Input, Icon } from 'native-base';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class MerchantRegister extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <ScrollView style={{
        paddingHorizontal: 30,
        paddingVertical: 20
      }}>

        <View style={{
          marginVertical: 10
        }}>

          <Label
            style={{
            fontSize: 14,
            marginBottom: 10
          }}>
            Contact Person
          </Label>
          <Item regular>
            <Input value={this.props.value.contactperson} onChangeText={value => this.props.handleChange("contactperson",value)}/>
          </Item>
        </View>

        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}



MerchantRegister.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default MerchantRegister;
```

Whenever I remove `{this.StepsofRegistrations()}` from Register Component it works fine but when I remove all the content from the `{this.StepsofRegistrations()}` this function this still gives me error.

Comment: Could You please show more precisely where do You pass props to child components?
I've also noticed your `MerchantRegister` Class component doesn't have `constructor()` function with called `super(props)` which is necessary if You want to use props in child.
And for that kind of complexity in state I would recommend You to think about using `Redux` or `Context API` to have shared state only when You need it and avoid passing it down at every level.

Comment: `return (<MerchantRegister value={this.state.merchantReg} handleChange={this._storetoState} />); ` This where I am passing state as value

Comment: and here I am accessing state as a prop `<Input value={this.props.value.contactperson} onChangeText={value => this.props.handleChange("contactperson",value)}/>`

Comment: Remove at least the async stuff from _storeToState, it is not needed there. You pattern otherwise is very similar I've used.

Comment: @Janne I removed async but no luck

Comment: @Janne Can you help me overcome the issue

Comment: Can you remove any parts of this code that are not actually relevant to this question? Right now it's just a wall of code and hard to see what the issue actually is. Try to make the example as minimal as possible.

Comment: And could You please share the full error text with us? Maybe it has a line of code where does this happen or something helpful.

Comment: @apokryfos I have removed some unwanted code could you please see them now

Comment: @RomanBatsenko I have shared the full error code can u please check them now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing async from `this.StepsofRegistrations()` worked for me.
But for more information you can look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37997990/4315757

Comment: General comment is that you need async calls only if you're really calling functions that return Promises (http requests, db requests etc.) When you play with your app locally you don't generally need to do any of those.