# Unhandled Rejection error when trying to map response array to state object

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to write a very simple React application that will send a GET request to an endpoint, and render the response on the page.  The response is in the form of an array (not JSON), and looks like (from Chrome dev tools):

```
h2Request.jsx:12
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {requestId: 173648899, type: -89}
    1: {requestId: 1917984867, type: -89}
    2: {requestId: 2097436650, type: -89}
    length: 3
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

My React app looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "../App.css";

class H2Request extends Component {
  state = {
    items: this.props.value
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8003").then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log("This object {}", this);
      this.setState({ items: response.data });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="button_container">
        <button className="button" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
          Refresh
        </button>
        <h1>Items: {this.state.items}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default H2Request;
```

But, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {requestId, type}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in h1 (at h2Request.jsx:24)
    in div (at h2Request.jsx:20)
     in H2Request (at src/index.js:7)

▶ 25 stack frames were collapsed.

(anonymous function)
src/components/h2Request.jsx:14
  11 |   axios.get("http://localhost:8003").then(response => {
  12 |     console.log(response.data);
  13 |     console.log("This object {}", this);
> 14 |     this.setState({ items: response.data });
  15 | ^ });
  16 | };
  17 |
```

From looking at my second log, `This object {}...` I can see that the current object does indeed have state updated, but I don't know why I get this error.

Comment: Its what the error says, you're trying to render `items` which is an array of objects. You can render an array of react elements, but an object will always break.

Comment: `{JSON.stringify(this.state.items, null, 2)}` or access properties in the object. You can't render an object directly like that.

Comment: or you can do `{(this.state.items || []).map((item) => item.requestId)}` or whatever you want to print instead of `item.requestId`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Promise Error: Objects are not valid as a React child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997893/promise-error-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child)

Comment: @ggorlen Your suggestion did the trick.  If you want to add an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear. Thanks, but I'd prefer to close it as a dupe. This sort of thing shows up in many forms and it's best to have a central, searchable answer for it since it's all the same fundamental problem, `this.state = {foo: {}}`... `return <div>{this.state.foo}</div>`.

Comment: No problem.  I've voted to have this closed as a dupe.  Thanks again.