# Conditional rendering if a prop contains a blank array

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to conditionally render based on an array having values in it. So basically if this.props.data == [] don't render. If this.props.data == [{data is here}] render.

Things I've tried.

if prop exists

```
{this.props.data && <Field 
                    label="Data" 
                    name="data" 
                    type="select" 
                    component={SelectComponent}>
                    <option>Select data</option>
                  </Field> }
```

===Still Renders===

null

```
{this.props.data != null && <Field 
                    label="Data" 
                    name="data" 
                    type="select" 
                    component={SelectComponent}>
                    <option>Select data</option>
                  </Field> }
```

===Still Renders===

length

```
{this.props.data.length > 0 && <Field 
                    label="Data" 
                    name="data" 
                    type="select" 
                    component={SelectComponent}>
                    <option>Select data</option>
                  </Field> }
```

===Length is not defined===

Comment: I'm not a React expert, but I think this is a similar issue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30142361/417562). `data` appears to be something other than an array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this:

```
{this.props.data && !!this.props.data.length && <Field 
                    label="Data" 
                    name="data" 
                    type="select" 
                    component={SelectComponent}>
                    <option>Select data</option>
                  </Field> }
```

So, check that the data is there and than check that it is not an empty array.

But I would recommend to pull it out into a method, because this way your render method can become messy really fast.

Comment: If `length` isn't defined, then it isn't an array.

Comment: Yes, I assume that initially the prop can be `undefined` or `null` before the actual data is fetched and later it becomes an array. That is why initially the `length` can be undefined.

Comment: this works but returns a 0 if the field doens't render. Any thoughts on removing that?

Comment: ah, that can be fixed by converting the length to boolean, like this: `!!this.props.data.length` or a little verbose, like this `Boolean(this.props.data.length)`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Brilliant! I will accept the answer when the 2 min timer expires. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: @GlebKost How can `this.props.data` be `undefined` or `null` and yet also be truthy?

Comment: @lonesomeday, It can not. Still, it can be an empty array: `[]` and be truthy. `Boolean([])` returns `true` in js.

Comment: @lonesomeday, so based on the original question, `this.props.data != null && <Field ...` will render the field if data is an empty array, `this.props.data.length > 0 && <Field  ...` will throw an error and break the program if data is `undefined` or `null`. Both are unwanted scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to react and  was setting my state as ``` === null``` or ```===false```  but this did the trick.

Comment: I finally got it working. I wrapped the condition rendering into the helper method. Logic and statements are  In the methods. I called it like this `{ MultiValidationErrorWrapper(errors) }`  and my component is inside like this `export const MultiValidationErrorWrapper = (errors) => {
  if ((errors) && (errors.length > 0)) {
    return <MultiValidationError errors={errors} />;
  }
};`
Thanks for help.