# NextJS | TypeError: items.map is not a function

Tags: next.js

This is the only error I am not being able to fix to move forward with my project.
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Building with NextJS 13. Error:

```
components/events/EventsList.js (8:15) @ EventsList

   6 | return (
   7 |   <ul>
>  8 |     {items.map((event) => (
     |           ^
   9 |       <EventItem
  10 |         key={event.id}
  11 |         id={event.id}
```

Full snippet of code:

```
import EventItem from "./EventItem";

function EventsList(props) {
    const { items } = props;
  
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map((event) => (
          <EventItem
            key={event.id}
            id={event.id}
            title={event.title}
            location={event.location}
            date={event.date}
            image={event.image}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

export default EventsList
```

Comment: ``items`` might not be an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142361/react-js-uncaught-typeerror-this-props-data-map-is-not-a-function

Comment: Where does `items` come from? Please provide a [mre].