# TypeScript categories.map is not a function

Tags: typescript, function, frontend, e-commerce, mern

I'm using TypeScript to build a MERN eCommerce website for a college end-of-year assignment. The website was functioning correctly and was nearly finished until I started getting this error in my code when there had never been any problem with it before, and I can't figure out how to fix it. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: categories.map is not a function
```

Here's my code:

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {
  Badge,
  Button,
  Container,
  Form,
  FormControl,
  InputGroup,
  ListGroup,
  Nav,
  Navbar,
  NavDropdown,
} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap'
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify'
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'
import { Store } from './Store'
import { useGetCategoriesQuery } from './hooks/productHooks'
import LoadingBox from './components/LoadingBox'
import MessageBox from './components/MessageBox'
import { getError } from './utils'
import { ApiError } from './types/ApiError'
import SearchBox from './components/SearchBox'

function App() {
  const {
    state: { mode, cart, userInfo },
    dispatch,
  } = useContext(Store)

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', mode)
  }, [mode])

  const switchModeHandler = () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SWITCH_MODE' })
  }
  const signoutHandler = () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'USER_SIGNOUT' })
    localStorage.removeItem('userInfo')
    localStorage.removeItem('cartItems')
    localStorage.removeItem('shippingAddress')
    localStorage.removeItem('paymentMethod')
    window.location.href = '/signin'
  }

  const [sidebarIsOpen, setSidebarIsOpen] = useState(false)

  const { data: categories, isLoading, error } = useGetCategoriesQuery()

  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
      <ToastContainer position="bottom-center" limit={1} />
      <header>
        <Navbar
          className="d-flex flex-column align-items-stretch p-2 pb-0 mb-3"
          bg="dark"
          variant="dark"
          expand="lg"
        >
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <LinkContainer to="/" className="header-link">
              <Navbar.Brand>TOME PHONE</Navbar.Brand>
            </LinkContainer>
            <SearchBox />

            <Navbar.Collapse>
              <Nav className="w-100 justify-content-end">
                <Link
                  to="#"
                  className="nav-link header-link"
                  onClick={switchModeHandler}
                >
                  <i
                    className={mode === 'light' ? 'fa fa-sun' : 'fa fa-moon'}
                  ></i>{' '}
                  {mode === 'light' ? 'Light' : 'Dark'}
                </Link>

                {userInfo ? (
                  <NavDropdown
                    className="header-link"
                    title={`Hello, ${userInfo.name}`}
                  >
                    <LinkContainer to="/profile">
                      <NavDropdown.Item>User Profile</NavDropdown.Item>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer to="/orderhistory">
                      <NavDropdown.Item>Order History</NavDropdown.Item>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <NavDropdown.Divider />
                    <Link
                      className="dropdown-item"
                      to="#signout"
                      onClick={signoutHandler}
                    >
                      {' '}
                      Sign Out{' '}
                    </Link>
                  </NavDropdown>
                ) : (
                  <NavDropdown className="header-link" title={`Hello, sign in`}>
                    <LinkContainer to="/signin">
                      <NavDropdown.Item>Sign In</NavDropdown.Item>
                    </LinkContainer>
                  </NavDropdown>
                )}
                <Link to="/orderhistory" className="nav-link header-link">
                  Orders
                </Link>
                <Link to="/cart" className="nav-link header-link p-0">
                  {
                    <span className="cart-badge">
                      {cart.cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.quantity, 0)}
                    </span>
                  }
                  <svg
                    fill="#ffffff"
                    viewBox="130 150 200 300"
                    width="40px"
                    height="40px"
                  >
                    <path d="M 110.164 188.346 C 104.807 188.346 100.437 192.834 100.437 198.337 C 100.437 203.84 104.807 208.328 110.164 208.328 L 131.746 208.328 L 157.28 313.233 C 159.445 322.131 167.197 328.219 176.126 328.219 L 297.409 328.219 C 306.186 328.219 313.633 322.248 315.951 313.545 L 341.181 218.319 L 320.815 218.319 L 297.409 308.237 L 176.126 308.237 L 150.592 203.332 C 148.426 194.434 140.675 188.346 131.746 188.346 L 110.164 188.346 Z M 285.25 328.219 C 269.254 328.219 256.069 341.762 256.069 358.192 C 256.069 374.623 269.254 388.165 285.25 388.165 C 301.247 388.165 314.431 374.623 314.431 358.192 C 314.431 341.762 301.247 328.219 285.25 328.219 Z M 197.707 328.219 C 181.711 328.219 168.526 341.762 168.526 358.192 C 168.526 374.623 181.711 388.165 197.707 388.165 C 213.704 388.165 226.888 374.623 226.888 358.192 C 226.888 341.762 213.704 328.219 197.707 328.219 Z M 197.707 348.201 C 203.179 348.201 207.434 352.572 207.434 358.192 C 207.434 363.812 203.179 368.183 197.707 368.183 C 192.236 368.183 187.98 363.812 187.98 358.192 C 187.98 352.572 192.236 348.201 197.707 348.201 Z M 285.25 348.201 C 290.722 348.201 294.977 352.572 294.977 358.192 C 294.977 363.812 290.722 368.183 285.25 368.183 C 279.779 368.183 275.523 363.812 275.523 358.192 C 275.523 352.572 279.779 348.201 285.25 348.201 Z" />
                  </svg>
                  <span>Cart</span>
                </Link>
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </div>
          <div className="sub-header">
            <div className="d-flex">
              <Link
                to="#"
                className="nav-link header-link p-1"
                onClick={() => setSidebarIsOpen(!sidebarIsOpen)}
              >
                <i className="fas fa-bars"></i> All
              </Link>
              {['Todays Deal', 'Gifts', 'On Sale'].map((x) => (
                <Link
                  key={x}
                  className="nav-link header-link p-1 px-3"
                  to={`/search?tag=${x}`}
                >
                  {x}
                </Link>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
      </header>

      {sidebarIsOpen && (
        <div
          onClick={() => setSidebarIsOpen(!sidebarIsOpen)}
          className="side-navbar-backdrop"
        ></div>
      )}

      <div
        className={
          sidebarIsOpen
            ? 'active-nav side-navbar d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-column'
            : 'side-navbar d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-column'
        }
      >
        <ListGroup variant="flush">
          <ListGroup.Item action className="side-navbar-user">
            <LinkContainer
              to={userInfo ? `/profile` : `/signin`}
              onClick={() => setSidebarIsOpen(!sidebarIsOpen)}
            >
              <span>
                {userInfo ? `Hello, ${userInfo.name}` : `Hello, sign in`}
              </span>
            </LinkContainer>
          </ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <strong>Categories</strong>
              <Button
                variant={mode}
                onClick={() => setSidebarIsOpen(!sidebarIsOpen)}
              >
                <i className="fa fa-times" />
              </Button>
            </div>
          </ListGroup.Item>
          {isLoading ? (
            <LoadingBox />
          ) : error ? (
            <MessageBox variant="danger">
              {getError(error as ApiError)}
            </MessageBox>
          ) : (
            categories!.map((category) => (
              <ListGroup.Item action key={category}>
                <LinkContainer
                  to={{ pathname: '/search', search: `category=${category}` }}
                  onClick={() => setSidebarIsOpen(false)}
                >
                  <Nav.Link>{category}</Nav.Link>
                </LinkContainer>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            ))
          )}
        </ListGroup>
      </div>

      <main>
        <Container className="mt-3">
          <Outlet />
        </Container>
      </main>
      <footer>
        <div className="text-center">All rights reserved</div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

any help would be greatly appreciated ! :)

I was looking at these websites

[https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-map-is-not-a-function#:~:text=The%20%22TypeError%3A%20map%20is%20not,call%20map%20on%20valid%20arrays](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-map-is-not-a-function#:%7E:text=The%20%22TypeError%3A%20map%20is%20not,call%20map%20on%20valid%20arrays).

[React JS - Uncaught TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142361/react-js-uncaught-typeerror-this-props-data-map-is-not-a-function)

Comment: the `!` in `categories!.map` means **I know it is always not undefined, be quite typescript complier** (however it doesn't), use `categories?.map` would be better

Comment: @Jerryh001 I tried that its giving me the same error. Thank you for replying

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your error is a javascript error occuring at runtime and not your linter highlighting a typescript typing issue.

I suggest you to console.log (or use debugger) to display the value of categories and check its correctly an array.

If its not, I suggest you to look inside the `useGetCategoriesQuery` hook. Its common when you use API call to specify an expected typescript type that is actually not matching the real api response.

Typescript act as a kind of documentation but don't check type at runtime.

You still able to hardcode some typing

```
const notANumber: number = "this is not a number" as number; // <-- will be accepted by typescript but you'll have issue at runtime if you use it as a number
```