# Uncaught TypeError: this.state.stock.map is not a function in React

Tags: reactjs

new to react, have seen some of the similar title as below but still could not clarify with the error getting on the console saying `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.stock.map is not a function` . When I use the similar code in the another api call then there is no such error coming. The code is as below for the same. If I am assigning data from the get method to stock the also its not working and giving the same issue. What is the problem ?  a few links that I  referred.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142361/react-js-uncaught-typeerror-this-props-data-map-is-not-a-function)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434789/react-js-this-props-data-map-is-not-a-function)

[Image after discussion.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv9nW.png)

```
var StockData = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            stock: []
        };
      },

      componentDidMount: function() {
        this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (data) {
           var old = JSON.stringify(data).replace("//", ""); //convert to JSON string
           var obj = JSON.parse(old);                        //convert back to JSON
           console.log(obj);
           this.setState({
              stock: obj
            });
        }.bind(this));
      },

      componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this.serverRequest.abort();
      },

      render: function() {
        return (
                React.createElement("div",null,
                        React.createElement("ul",null,
                            this.state.stock.map(function (listValue){
                                return React.createElement("li",null,listValue.t,"( ",listValue.e," )-"," Current Price :",listValue.l_cur,"  Date :",listValue.lt
                                );
                            })
                        )
                    )
        );
      }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(StockData, { source: "http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:ATULAUTO,WIPRO,INFY" }),document.getElementById('proper-list-render3'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace render function with stored this as self

```
 render: function() {
        var self = this;
        return (
                React.createElement("div",null,
                        React.createElement("ul",null,
                            self.state.stock.map(function (listValue){
                                return React.createElement("li",null,listValue.t,"( ",listValue.e," )-"," Current Price :",listValue.l_cur,"  Date :",listValue.lt
                                );
                            })
                        )
                    )
        );
      }
```

Comment: Still the issue persists.

Comment: can u console.log(this.state) in the render .I gues this.state.stock might not be array .lets see

Comment: check the image attached to the question.

Comment: stock is a json strngified string

Comment: Server returned json string and in componentDidmount , you stringified it and then parsed it , end result is a string

Comment: But i am using JSON.parse and assigning the same to stock, so it should be JSON object. Then need to parse `this.state` to JSON ?

Comment: try   stock = json.parse(this.state.stock) in the render function and use the stock in loop

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution to the problem. The data received after calling the url is received in the string format and not JSON. The correct code is as below and now it is working fine. Thanks @Piyush.kapoor for the help.

```
  componentDidMount: function() {
        this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (data) {     
           var old = data.replace("//", "");   
           this.setState({   
                    stock: JSON.parse(old)   
               });
        }.bind(this));
      }
```