# React JS - Uncaught TypeError: props.video.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and trying to debug the following errors I am seeing.

**Error #1:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: props.videos.map is not a function
at new VideoList
```

**Error #2:**

```
bundle.js:19956 Error: findComponentRoot(..., .0.0.0): Unable to find element.
This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), 
usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like 
<form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG elements in an <svg> parent. 
Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``.
```

Here is my code in reference to this file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';

const VideoList = (props) => {
  const videoItems = props.videos.map((video) => {
    return <VideoListItem key={video.etag} video={video} />
  });
  return (
    <ul className ="col-md-4 list-group">
    {videoItems}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default VideoList;
```

Index.js file:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import VideoList from './components/video_list'
const API_KEY = '';



// create a new component.  This component should produce
// some HTML

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { videos: {} };

    YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'React'}, (videos) => {
      this.setState({ videos });
    });
  }

  render() {
  return (

  <div>
  <SearchBar />
  <VideoList videos={this.state.videos} />
  </div>
);
}
}
// Take this component's generated HTML and put it
// on the page (in the DOM)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

I reviewed the following questions on SOF but neither could resolve my issue:

[React JS - Uncaught TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142361/react-js-uncaught-typeerror-this-props-data-map-is-not-a-function)

[React.js this.props.data.map() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434789/react-js-this-props-data-map-is-not-a-function)

What I am having a hard time understanding is why it's giving me error #1 because I am using the function declaration with the 'fat arrows'.  And I assume Error #2 is a result of Error #1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try logging `props.videos` and make sure it is an array, even an empty one. If it's not an array or undefined this error can happen.

Comment: I was about to ask the propose the same thing :)

Comment: Hi @AlexanderStaroselsky! Thanks for the suggestion.  I did try `console.log(props.videos);` just now but it didn't seem to return anything in the console.

Comment: Did you try it right before the `const videoItems ...` within the `VideoList` body? The goal is to see the structure and type of `props` or `props.videos`. You will likely get around this error by default videos to an empty array if no videos exist or similar.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky ah that was a mistake! I didn't do it before the constant.  I just did it and it now returns the protocols but no error messages or anything I can use to debug it.  I'll look more into the '_protos_'.

Comment: `map()` is an array function. It cannot be applied to an object. It looks like you are defaulting `videos` to an object rather than empty array `[]`. Does the data come in as an array? Or as an object in `YTSearch`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky before when the code was working the results were returned as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `videos` default state to an empty array `[]` rather than object `{}`:

```
this.state = { videos: [] };
```

This error is happening because [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is an array method and is simply not available on objects.

Comment: Woah! That was it.  Can't believe I didn't see that! Now I know where to check next time.  THANKS so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this method.

```
 const videoItems = props.videos && props.videos.map((video) => {
    return <VideoListItem key={video.etag} video={video} />
  });
```

Maybe props.video is undefined before it can render.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it but I am seeing the same error message.

Comment: I included the other file in the question now.  Thanks!